# how to convert string Tensor to Tensor float list?

Tags: tensorflow, casting, shapes, reshape, tensor

So, my code is like

```
    parsed_line = tf.decode_csv(line, [[0], [0], [""]])
    print(parsed_line[0])
    del parsed_line[0]
    del parsed_line[0]
    features = parsed_line
    print(parsed_line[0])
```

then the result is

```
    [<tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:1' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:2' shape=() dtype=string>]
```

and

```
    [<Tensor("DecodeCSV:2", shape=(), dtype=string)>]
```

the csv i will give to this decode function is

```
    1, 0, 0101010010101010101010
```

and I want this "0101010010101010101010" to

```
    [0,1,0,1,0,.........]
```

in tensorflow

```
    [<Tensor("DecodeCSV:2", shape=(), dtype=string)>]
```

to

```
    [<tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:1' shape=() dtype=int32>, ............]
```

do you have any ideas of this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it this way using [`tf.string_split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split) and [`tf.string_to_number`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_to_number):

```
import tensorflow as tf

line = tf.constant("1000111101", shape=(1,))
b = tf.string_split(line, delimiter="").values
c = tf.string_to_number(b, tf.int32)
print(c)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))
```

> [1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]